# Only show `no results` on getjson once per request

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm currently showing a `No results` message when the request response returns `0`. However, it displays more than once as the user types. It then does not clear the message when the user enters a term which has a response count larger than 0.

**jQuery**

```
$("#results-container").hide();
 $("#global-search").keyup(function(e) {
   var q = $("#global-search").val();
     if(e.which == 13) {
             window.location.replace("/search?q=" + q);
     }
   //Only begin search with at least 3 characters.
   if(q.length > 3){
         $("#results-container").show();
      ajax_search();
   }
   //Send search query
   function ajax_search(){
   $.getJSON("//search.url-to-data.com?q=" + q, {

     },
     //Get results and make 'em look good
     function(data) {
              if(data.count == 0){
                    $(".search-results").hide();
                    $("#results-container").append("<p>No results available. Please try another search.</p>");
                }else{
                    $(".search-results").show();
                }
             $(".practice-area-results, .group-results").empty();
             console.log(data);
         $.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
                     if(data.type === "Practice Area"){
                        $(".practice-area-results").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"" + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
                        if($(".practice-area-results").text() === ""){
                            $(".practice-area-results-header, .practice-area-results").empty();
                        }
                     }else if(data.type === "Group"){
             $(".group-results").append("<li class='result-item'><a href=\"" + data.permalink + "\">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
                         if($(".group-results").text() === ""){
                             $(".group-results-header, .group-results").hide()
                         }
                     }
             });
      });
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row desktop-search">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="global-search" style="width:100%; position: fixed;" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
      <div id="results-container">
        <div class="search-results">
          <p class="practice-area-results-header">Practice Area</p>
          <div class="practice-area-results"></div>
          <p class="group-results-header">Group</p>
          <div class="group-results"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why not just put the message in a separate `div` and then show it when there are no results and hide it when results are returned?

Comment: I had done that too, adding `$(".no-result").append("<p>No results available. Please try another search.</p>");` to a `<div class="no-result"></div>` within `<div id="results-container">`, but it returns the no results message more than once.

Comment: That's not the same thing. You're not hiding and showing a single `div`. You're adding new content each time.

Comment: Doing this: `if(data.count == 0){$(".search-results").hide(); $(".no-result").show();}else{$(".no-result").hide();$(".search-results").show();}` is a step in the right direction, but it still shows the no results message for a second before actual results are returned if the query returns data.